# Настройка toast notifications в wpf-приложении

Tags: c#, wpf

Здравствуйте.

Работаю над WPF-приложением, в котором необходим функционал оповещения пользователя.

Выбираю между сторонними решениями и стандартными для Windows 8/10 toast notifications.

Вызывать обычные toast notifications удается благодаря решению, приведенному в [этом примере](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Sending-toast-notifications-71e230a2), однако не удается указать цвет оповещения, оно всегда темно-серое.

В обсуждении того же примера есть предположение, что это можно сделать через манифест приложения, по аналогии с WinRT-приложениями, но пока добиться нужного результата не удалось.

Если кто-то сталкивался с подобной задачей, подскажите пожалуйста какие есть пути её решения, все же существует необходимость использования именно стандартных оповещений.

Заранее спасибо

Comment: Вот это не помогло: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15330636/276994?

Comment: А, понял, это для Metro app, а у вас Desktop? У вас есть manifest? Вот [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23203369/276994) говорят о `WMAppManifest.xml`.

Comment: Да, у меня Desktop. Во второй ссылке говорится о приложении для Windows Phone